# How to interpret rules to make the serial killer from the movie "Relentless?"

Tags: dnd-3.5e

The serial killer in [Relentless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relentless_%281989_film%29) (1989) was able to grapple and control his victims enough to make them hold the murder weapon(s) and force them to finish themselves off.

I am unaware of grapple rules that allow such a thing. Is there a way I can build a character who can do this?

Any level, any class, and any book is allowed. I would rather rely less on magic if possible. I will customize the campaign around him.

[image: the relentless movie poster]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## This option's available to any grappler

Attacking a foe with a weapon he still wields is a grapple benefit available to anyone, requiring no special feats or features.

> **Use Opponent’s Weapon**
> If your opponent is holding a light weapon, you can use it to attack him. Make an opposed grapple check (in place of an attack). If you win, make an attack roll with the weapon with a -4 penalty (doing this doesn’t require another action).
>
> You don’t gain possession of the weapon by performing this action.

Thus as long as the serial killer A) goes after folks he can consistently beat in grapple checks who B) are armed with light weapons, you, too, can have a late 80s cheesy action movie villain in your *D&D 3.5* game.

Comment: Well, assuming an opposed grapple check at the same penalty to put the light weapon in their hands... and then using this option to do the deed... I am ashamed I wasn't aware of this grappling option earlier. Thanks.

Comment: @Ruut "at the same penalty" - The penalty in this action is for the attack (it is the one that applies to any mid-grapple attack), not the opposed grapple check. Consider using a straight-up opposed grapple, or perhaps disarm rolls/modifiers for placing the weapon; it's a disarm in reverse, after all.

Comment: @Ruut If the killer says to the lone unarmed victim that he's going to murder the victim **then offers the victim a dagger** (perhaps tossing it at the victim's feet... sigh, *trust issues*), the victim will *probably* take the dagger. From there, for an optimized grappling serial killer, it's smooth sailing. (Although such a grappler would probably inflict more damage by making attacks unarmed.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Yeah. I am looking at the Knifefighter feat and the Scorpion's Grasp feats. Thanks!